# Extracting elements from a array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a array of dictionaries. From here I want to extract individual elements

The following code is generating an array which has multiple dictionaries. From this I need to extract values which match a certain key.

Code used:

```
return array.filter{namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}
```

This looks like:

> [["a":"1","b":"2","c":3],["a":"3","b":"4","c":5]]

From this I need to extract values for key "a" ie 1, 3. How do I go about this?

Comment: Unrelated: I would recommend you try to avoid heterogeneously typed dictionaries, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compactMap`:

```
let aValues = filteredArray.compactMap { $0["a"] }
```

where `filteredArray` is the array returned from `array.filter{namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}`.

Answer (score 0):

please informed that, the filter will return the same type as the array it self, the map will return the new type you mean to return. so if you want to get the different type with it self, you need to use map function.
and in map functions "map" will return the same number of elements as the array it self, the "compactMap" will remove the 'nil' value.
so if you make sure all the 'dict' in your array have the key you need to get, you can use `map`, or you can you use `compactMap`  to avoid nil value in the result array

so you can use

```
let arr = [["a":"1","b":"2","c":3],["a":"3","b":"4","c":5]]

let test = arr.map{$0["a"] as? String}
let test2 = arr.compactMap{$0["a"] as? String}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do with for multiple keys, you can make a merged dictionary that maps all keys to arrays of all values. You lose the ordering of the values, so this will only work if it's not necessary.

```
func merge<Key, Value>(dicts: [[Key: Value]]) -> [Key: [Value]] {
    return dicts.reduce(into: [:]) { accumalatorDict, dict in
        accumalatorDict.merge(
            dict.mapValues({ [$0] }),
            uniquingKeysWith: { return $0 + $1 }
        )
    }
}

let dicts: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["a":"1","b":"2","c":3],
    ["a":"3","b":"4","c":5]
]

let mergedDicts = merge(dicts: dicts)

for (key, values) in mergedDicts {
    print(key, values)
}

let allValuesForA = mergedDicts["a"]
print(allValuesForA) // => ["1", "3"]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
let arr = [["a":"1","b":"2","c":3],["a":"3","b":"4","c":5]]

let test = arr.map{$0["a"] as? String}
```